# How to create a new object and assign properties in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to bridge an Objective C SDK with React Native and I'm having some trouble. I have a Subclass of NSObject and I'm trying to set some property values but I can't get it to work.

I have tried to change the property in the header, and in the imp file with out any difference.

PrinterSDK.h (which has libPrinterSDK.a)

```
@interface Printer : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString* name;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString* UUIDString;

@end
```

RNPosPrint.m

```
@interface Printer ()
@property (readwrite) NSString* name;
@property (readwrite) NSString* UUIDString;
@end

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(printTestPaper:(NSString*)name:(NSString*)uuid)
{

  Printer* printer = [[Printer alloc] init];   
  printer.name = name;

}
```

But I keep facing issue with the setter for some reason I can't figure out.

```
ExceptionsManager.js:94 Exception '-[Printer setPrinterName:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x13fd25b90' was thrown while invoking printTestPaper on target RNPosPrint with params (
    "Test Printer",
    "XXX-XXX-XXX"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not report the *names* of your `.h` and `.m` files or what else is in the `.m` – e.g. `@implementation` of `Printer`? The class `printTestPaper` belongs to? Without details like this it is difficult for anyone to help you, you need to help people help you.

That said some points that may help you:

- The `@interface Printer ()` where you open up the properties to be writeable should be in the your `Printer.m` file – in general do not try to open up access to a type's properties from outside the type's implementation, it is both bad design and may not work as you hope (as you just found out).
- The code to support a `@property` is generated by the compiler when it compiles the `@implementation`, `@interface`'s themselves produce no executable code – they describe the accessible parts of the `@implementation`.
- `setter=<name>` provides a different name for the auto-created property setter function. While a method `<name>` will be created to set the property using dot syntax the properties name is still used, e.g. in your case `printer.name = ...` is still used even with the `setter=setPrinterName:`. You can call the auto-created method using standard method syntax, that failed in your case for the reasons above.
- Using `setter=<name>` or `getter=<name>` are really advanced features and you probably will never need to use them – when you do need to use them you will know! Just avoid them till then.
- If you wish to provide a method which creates the object and sets properties then do this in the type's implementation. The usual way of doing this is to provide an `init` method that does this, e.g. in this case it might be `- initWithName:(NSString *)printerName { ... }`, or an equivalent class method which does the allocation and sets the parameters, e.g. in this case it might be `+ newWithName:(NSString *)printerName { ... }`.

HTH

Comment: After spending some more time and learning Objective C I know understand I left out some important information in my question.

The interface was from a statically linked library which cannot be modified. I simply had to solve it by using the scan method which had the callback that returned the Printer object.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's an interface from statically linked library it is simply not possible to extend or manipulate. Not without tempering with the compiler.